# Are there any Methods that reads mysql tables and creates classes dynamically in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to know whether there exists any **classes/methods** in **codeigniter** that creates **MODEL Classes** for a mysql table dynamically?

In .net there is a tool that do this kind of functionality -- **CODESMITH**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of native CI functionality to create model classes for your database. Remember that CodeIgniter's Active record is not an ORM. You could opt in for a 3rd party ORM, like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) which, based on your schema or DB structure, could populate model classes.